# Android Lollipop Material design tabs animation

Tags: android, android-layout

Im trying to start with android material design and maybe im starting with hard part, "tabs".
My question is, How i can my tabs do the animation in example below
[Tab touch target animation](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs)

I also tried run this sample [SlidingtTabs sample](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html) ,but in example tabs dont have animation on touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lollipop** *animations* are not supported, so for :

**Pre-Lollipop :**

I use [rippleeffect](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect) library to acheive this animaton.

**Lolipop :**

**From XML**

```
<ripple android:color="#ff00ff00">
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue"/>
</ripple>
```

**From Code**

```
RippleDrawable ripple = new RippleDrawable(
new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE), null);
ripple.setColor(myList);
```

**Or**

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```